# JSON standards - and polymorphism

Tags: python, .net, json, jackson, polymorphism

We are primarily `Java` shop with `Spring`/`Hibernate` etc. We have `REST` based `API` that is consumed by our customers who may or may not be using `Java`.

One of the problems our customers face is converting object to concrete type because of polymorphism.

If all our customers were using `Java/Spring`, I can tinker settings of object mapper to return information about types. One such example can be found at  [baeldung and polymorphism](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)

I'm not clear if type information embedded generated `JSON` is considered as valid `JSON` by other `JSON` parsers say in `Python`/`Node`-`Javascript`/`.NET` etc and whether it will break their code.

Are there any standards when it comes to type information embedded in `JSON` like `Jackson` does it. Google search did not reveal much.

Comment: @MichałZiober, it was little useful, I did up vote it, but did not accept it as I was hoping for some more answers

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am just curious.

Comment: @MichałZiober, not really, I ended up using JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS as a quick fix. Looking at documentation, I think Id.NAME can be used more elegantly, but did not get a chance to play with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one standard which all frameworks must follow. Even `Jackson` can do that on many different ways whatever user decide to use. Also `Jackson` always generate `valid JSON` even when whole class name is used such as `"org.baeldung.jackson.inheritance.Car"` or `"org.baeldung.jackson.inheritance.Truck"`. To make it work and easy to use you must clarify all `base types` and `subtypes` in:

- documentation
- `JSon Schema`

There is no point to send whole `class` name because non `Java` clients will not recognise them automatically anyway. So, you need to create mapping:

- `BP` - base product
- `P1` - product 1
- `P2` - product 2
- ...

You also mast to specify, that for example, each object contains `"type"` property which will be set to one from above list:

```
[
   {
      "type":"P1",
      "model":"S500",
      "cost":250.0
   },
   {
      "type":"P2",
      "model":"NQR",
      "capacity":7500.0
   }
]
```

Above should provide enough information to `deserialise` any `payload`.